# Draw a circle at cursor position using fragment shader on a non square canvas

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm just getting started with shaders and am having trouble drawing a circle based on the cursor position without it appearing as an ellipses.

I'm using the following fragment shader (via Shadertoy):

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 st = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;

    float m_x = iMouse.x / iResolution.x;
    float m_y = iMouse.y / iResolution.y;

    vec3 m_color = vec3(1.0);

    float mouse_pct = distance(vec2(m_x, m_y), st);
    mouse_pct = step(0.01, mouse_pct);
    m_color = vec3(mouse_pct);


    fragColor = vec4(m_color, 1.0);
}
```

I can make the ellipses a circle by adding:

`st.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;`

However this results in the circle being drawn in the wrong place on the X axis (this also doesn't feel like the right way to do this). I think I'm generally confused about how one would draw a shape that isn't based on the whole canvas and am unsure what I should be searching for to fill that gap in my understanding.

[Shadertoy link](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XttBRH) - you need to click and drag to change the mouse position.

Comment: Why divide by resolution in the first place? Working with pixel coordinates seems much more straightforward.

Comment: @riv Honestly, because thats what was done in thebookofshaders, which is what I'm learning from, so this method is all I know. It's a good point though... I might rewrite it using absolute pixel coords and see if I find that more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tor respect the aspect ratio on the vector of the fragment point to the center point of the circle:

```
vec2 dist = vec2(m_x, m_y) - st.xy;
dist.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;
```

Change your code somehow like this:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 st = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;

    vec2 dist = iMouse/iResolution - st.xy;
    dist.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;

    float mouse_pct = length(dist);

    mouse_pct = step(0.3, mouse_pct);
    vec3 m_color = vec3(mouse_pct);
    fragColor = vec4(m_color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: This works :) - I'm still getting my head around it but it's working now so thanks! It will make more sense as I use it more I'm sure :p